# How to take count of status field from mongo db collection in laravel eloquent raw method?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How to write group by and count status in laravel eloquent raw method?
I am using mongodb.

For testing purpose I took the count using mysql (result and query given below) but I don't know how to take count in mongodb.

Please check collections and code given below. Thanks

**SQL**

`SELECT count(*), status, date FROM booking WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31' group by status, date order by date`

**Results**

`count status date
 3      1    2017-08-01
 1      2    2017-08-01
 2      2    2017-08-02
 1      3    2017-08-02
 1      1    2017-08-03
 1      2    2017-08-03
 1      1    2017-08-04
 1      2    2017-08-04
 1      3    2017-08-04
 1      3    2017-08-05
 2      2    2017-08-06
 2      3    2017-08-07
 1      1    2017-08-08
 1      2    2017-08-08
 1      3    2017-08-08
 1      1    2017-08-09
 1      2    2017-08-09`

**Controller.php**

```
$bookings               = Booking::raw(function ($collection) use ($cabinName, $dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => [
                            'is_delete' => 0,
                            'cabinname' => $cabinName,
                            'checkin_from' => ['$gte' => $dateBegin, '$lte' => $dateEnd]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' =>
                            [
                                '_id' => ['checkin_from' => '$checkin_from','cabinname' => '$cabinname'],

                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$project' =>
                            [
                                'checkin_from' => '$_id.checkin_from',
                                'cabinname' => '$_id.cabinname',

                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$sort' =>
                            [
                                'checkin_from' => 1
                            ],
                    ],
                ]);
            });
```

**Mongo collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07a4f2017f945660bc1d"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07b5f2017f945660bc1e"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07c3f2017f945660bc1f"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07cdf2017f945660bc20"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-01T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07f5f2017f945660bc21"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c07fef2017f945660bc22"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c0802f2017f945660bc23"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08a4f2017f945660bc24"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-03T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08acf2017f945660bc25"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-03T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08bcf2017f945660bc26"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08c3f2017f945660bc27"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08cef2017f945660bc28"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08dff2017f945660bc29"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-05T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08eef2017f945660bc2a"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-06T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c08f3f2017f945660bc2b"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-06T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c0901f2017f945660bc2c"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-07T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c0905f2017f945660bc2d"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-07T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c090ef2017f945660bc2e"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-08T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c091af2017f945660bc2f"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-08T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("598c091ff2017f945660bc30"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-08T00:00:00Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(0), "status" : NumberLong(1) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the raw query with count and group by.

**Controller.php**

```
$bookings               = Booking::raw(function ($collection) use ($cabinName, $dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => [
                            'is_delete' => 0,
                            'cabinname' => $cabinName,
                            'checkin_from' => ['$gte' => $dateBegin, '$lte' => $dateEnd]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' =>
                            [
                                '_id' => ['checkin_from' => '$checkin_from','cabinname' => '$cabinname','status' => '$status'],
                                'count' => ['$sum' => 1]
                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$project' =>
                            [
                                'checkin_from' => '$_id.checkin_from',
                                'cabinname' => '$_id.cabinname',
                                'status' => '$_id.status',
                                'count' => 1,
                            ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$sort' =>
                            [
                                'checkin_from' => 1
                            ],
                    ],
                ]);
            });
```